# How can I ensure that the onUrlChange in WebView called only once when navigating?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, webview

The package used for WebView is: https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter

The current issue I'm facing is that when navigating from Home.dart to WebViewPage.dart using navigator push, onUrlChange is being called twice. However, I need to call other widgets in onUrlChange, so how can I ensure that onUrlChange is only called once each time I enter WebViewPage.dart and not repeatedly?

**1. Home.dart:**

```
Navigator.of(context).push(SlideAnimationRoute(
  builder: (_) {
    return WebViewPage(webviewUrl);
  },
));
```

**2. WebViewPage.dart:**

```
class WebViewPage extends StatefulWidget {
  String _url;

  WebViewPage(this._url);

  @override
  _WebViewState createState() => _WebViewState();
} 

class _WebViewState extends State<WebViewPage> {
  final Completer<WebViewController> _controller =
      Completer<WebViewController>();

  late WebViewController _webViewController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _webViewController = WebViewController()  
      ..setNavigationDelegate(
        NavigationDelegate(
          onWebResourceError: (WebResourceError error) {},
          onUrlChange: (UrlChange change) async {
            try {
              // Do something at here
            } catch (e) {
              print('Error during navigation: $e');
            }
          },
        ),
      )
      ..loadRequest(Uri.parse(widget._url));
  }
}
```

Comment: You mean twice, by one time when navigating to the widget and a second time when the loadRequest is triggered?

Comment: When I navigate from the native application to a web view, specifically through Navigator push, it may be invoked more than once. However, when navigating to a new page within the web view, onUrlChange returns to normal and is called only once.